# How do I know all messages of a specific job in a Kafka Topic have been consumed by S3 Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am trying to consume messages from a Kafka Topic using S3 Sink Connector.

I want to close this connector and delete Kafka Topic when a specific number of records have been processed and written to S3 objects.

The number of records to be consumed can be queried from a ksqlDB table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no numeric trigger available in Kafka Connect framework to do this.

You could write a Lambda to read every file written to S3, as Connect writes them, count the number of records (and persist the value in something like DynamoDB or Elasticache) for every file, then when you reach your limit, you can send an HTTP call to delete the connector, and kafka `AdminClient` delete-topics action.

ksqlDB has its own consumer, and counter, and doesn't read data from S3 to know how many events were actually written out.